# What does "tracatera" mean?

Tags: traducción, palabras-raras, definiciones

I've been collecting unusual Spanish words for years. I've been going through them to find any that are not in my dictionaries and found this one:

> tracatera *f*

It's not in the DRAE, it's not in Wiktionary (though it's in the requested entries list there), it's not in my Larousse Gran Diccionario, and Google Translate doesn't handle it.

It is easy to find using a plain old Google search or even a [Google Books search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=tracatera&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=tracatero%20OR%20tracatera%20OR%20tracateros%20OR%20tracateras&pbx=1&oq=tracatero%20OR%20tracatera%20OR%20tracateros%20OR%20tracateras&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=147204l157493l1l157737l41l36l0l0l0l0l997l10352l0.3.21.8.2.0.1l35l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c481cb41a54360c&biw=853&bih=417). It does seem to be a feminine noun and not just a feminine version of a noun or adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tracatera" es un término coloquial (¿posiblemente onomatopéyico?) usado en México para referirse a una "balacera"; he aquí una estrofa de uno de los así denominados "Narco-corridos" en el que se utiliza "tracatera":

> Sonaba la tracatera
>
> seis federales lloraban
>
> aprovechó ese momento
>
> y se subió a su blindada
>
> así salió de su casa
>
> pura madre lo paraban.

Comment: Just for a moment I think that tracatera comes from "matraca".